# open FileOpen protected pdf files in python

Tags: python, drm

does anyone know how to open [FileOpen](https://www.fileopen.com/) protected PDF file in python? I have the username and password. I just have no idea how to integrate the FileOpen plug-in with python. My current approach is to use python to open and log in to Adobe Reader(with FileOpen plug-in installed) and to take screenshots of the pages. However this is not ideal.

Comment: Maybe add some details on the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to permanently remove any DRM protected PDF as long as you can view it. I have actual Python code but won't post it here.

In this case, you open the PDF with any reader with FileOpen plugin installed. Then you use pyautogui to take screenshot of each pages and save them as a new PDF. You will need to OCR your new PDF if you wish it to be searchable.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [PDFMINER](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/). I have not used it but according to their specs it supports passwords.